# InsecureRequestWarning while doing aws s3 ls s3://[mybucketname:)] --no-verify-ssl

Tags: amazon-web-services

```
aws s3 ls s3://umd-stg-view --no-verify-ssl
/home1/aaaa/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1004:
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is
strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning,
```

I have done to get the list of s3 bucket but failed with above the error message.
At first, I set the aws configure also

```
$ aws configure list
  Name                    Value             Type    Location
  ----                    -----             ----    --------
profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************IRMK shared-credentials-file    
secret_key     ****************CGXM shared-credentials-file    
region                us-east-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

I added "--no-verify-ssl" option...

How to I access aws s3 bucket with aws cli?

Comment: Why would you use `--no-verify-ssl` in this case? This warning is standard `urllib3` warning which is displayed in such case, it is not an error or failure in and of itself. Command should produce a correct result.